# how to make custom month calender in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

as you can see i want to achieve that specifc UI in my flutter app where i have to show user dates and shifts on that specific day

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCTko.png)

i try to achieve it using gridview but i am having problem at mobile while it is working somehow on web.i need it in mobile and web version as well

`     Widget buildCalendar() {
final int daysInMonth =
DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month + 1,   0).day;
final int firstDayWeekday =
DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, 1).weekday;

```
  List<Widget> calendarCells = [];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  calendarCells.add(
    Container(
      // Decrease vertical padding
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black87,

        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          daysOfWeek[i],
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
for (int i = 0; i < firstDayWeekday; i++) {
  calendarCells.add(Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey),
      ),
    ),
  )); // Empty cell for days before the first day of the month
}

for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
  final date = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, day);
  final shiftsForDate = getShiftsForDate(date);

  calendarCells.add(
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        // Handle tap on a specific date
        print('Tapped on $date');
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 10,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: kIsWeb? CrossAxisAlignment.start:CrossAxisAlignment.center,

          // Center the content vertically
          children: [
            Text('$day'),
            const SizedBox(height: 4), // Decrease spacing
            Column(
              children: shiftsForDate.map((shift) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment:kIsWeb? CrossAxisAlignment.start:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                  children: [
                    Text('${shift.name}'),
                   if(kIsWeb)...[ Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('Start: ${shift.startTime}'),
                        Text('End: ${shift.endTime}'),

                      ],
                    ),]
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  // Add a divider line after each week
}

// Add a default container to ensure a non-null return value
calendarCells.add(Container(

));

return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 7,
    childAspectRatio: 0.9,
  ),
  itemCount: calendarCells.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return calendarCells[index];
  },
);
```

}

`

here is the image from mobile and web as you can see how much work is done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xwdW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAfIs.png)